# Assigning Strong Name to Third Party DLL

Tags: iis, c#-4.0, strong-named-key

I am trying to profile an IIS web Service Hosted on a different Machine through VSTS Command Line Tools. During this Process My(CommercialService.dll) file becomes Unsigned. 
So I resign my above Dll with same certificate  and same public key token according to procedure mentioned in http://sharepointcoding.wordpress.com/2009/02/27/assign-a-strong-name-to-a-third-party-dll/ and make a new Dll (rj.dll) to make it protected again.

When I try to replace CommercialService.Dll with  rj.dll(by changing it’s name)  I got from above procedure , I am not able to deploy it on IIS.